# Generate API client interface and use it in frontend project

Tags: .net, typescript, npm, azure-devops, swagger-codegen

Our dev team would like to auto generate typescript interfaces from our .NET backend REST API and use it in our frontend project (Angular/typescript).

The backend and frontend each have their own GIT repositories.

I figured we would use swagger-codegen to generate the interfaces, but I'm not sure how we would go about getting them into our frontend.

One solution would be to create a private npm package and use it in the frontend.

Another solution would be to use GIT submodules, but I would rather not go that route after having worked with them before :)

Is there a better/simpler solution to this?

Comment: So, the .net code generates the typescript files and the front-end will consume it, is that what you mean ? If yes, why don't you build the functionality within .net and use it directly from the front-end ? All you'll have to do is to enable CORS. In one of our project, we've a similar set-up where front-end and back-end is completely different. (backend in .net api and front-end is Angular/typescript). They are happily married with CORS.

Comment: @Sukhi The idea is to get the backend to generate typescript interfaces that describe what the backend endpoints will return. I need these generated files within my frontend project. What do you mean by "use it directly"? I'm not sure we are talking about the same thing :)

Comment: Okay. Perhaps I didn't understand the use case well. By "use it directly" I meant the following. Your idea is to create typescript files by .net. So, your team will kind of write a program to write another program. Instead, why not use the original program itself to achieve the desired functionality which otherwise you are intending to do via typescript. In this case, the only typescript you'll have to write is to call the end-point.

Answer (score 0):

We have this issue few years ago, and at the end I have decided to make a tool for generating API from Open API.
[Swagger-typescript](https://github.com/hosseinmd/swagger-typescript)

- generate for JavaScript and Typescript
- support node and browser (axios under the hood)
- generate hooks for react/react-native (react-query under the hood)
- support git branch management automatically (Git flow)
- support multiple gateway
- support update partially (to avoid git conflict)